# Moving GMSPanoramaView stacks up memory

Tags: swift, google-maps, memory, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-street-view

I am creating an app that presents different locations in street view. But every time a new place is loading, the memory used is increased. This later leads to the app crashing. Is there any way to clear memory of past loaded street views?
[The memory goes up every time a panorama is loaded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Agzf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1: test memory usage on device and not in simulator

2: remember ARC can free up memory when it decides too. Unless you really tell it to do so.

Did testing on device helped?